# Connecting Xbee to Arduino Micro

Tags: arduino, xbee

I have found the following schematics: [image: xbee]

How to modify this now to work from the Arduino Micros 5V output voltage (I will run it on 5V)?

For diode can I just use 1N4001 or similar diodes?

As this hooks on the serial port I assume that once the Xbee is connected it will be impossible to program the arduino from the IDE just like it would be connected to other device on it's serial port which always causing the programmer to fail with stk500() error. For this I could put in a double sided switch to be able to detach the xbee when I want to program the ardu once the device is assembled.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to interface the voltage levels is to use a voltage level converter/shifter You can buy these off the shelf as a finished product or make them yourself using transistors/opamps.

For the diode you need to check its frequency response. Its better to use a signal diode in this application (such as 1n148) as it can handle higher switching rates without distortion. This will ensure a more reliable design.

A double sided switch would work to enable programming. However, you can easily emulate another serial port using software serial as explained [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial).